# How to connect implemtations to closing types in structuremap, when dynamically instantiating objects

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have a project which has commands and command executors classes, which take the given command and do something.

I use structuremap and generics to find and create and instance of an exector for any given command that I want to run in my system.

for example:

I have a base executor class

```
public abstract class BaseExecutor<T> : IExecutor<T>
{
//do something
}
```

and this is an example of an executor which should be created by structure map for the command class of: MyFakeCommand

```
public class MyFakeCommandExecutor : BaseExecutor<MyFakeCommand>
{
    public void Run(MyFakeCommand cmd)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

To connect the executors to the command, configure structure map by calling ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing.

```
public void RegisterExecutionAssembly<T>()
{
    IocContainer.Configure(c => c.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.AssemblyContainingType<T>();
        scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IExecutor<>));
    }));
}
```

and to find an executor for a given command I call the following

```
public IExecutor<T> GetExecutorFor<T>()
{
    return IocContainer.GetAllInstances<IExecutor<T>>().FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

So to run an executor for a command I can do something like this:

```
var cmd = new MyFakeCommand();
var executor = GetExecutorFor(cmd);
executor.Run(cmd);
```

this all works fine, until I start to create the commands dynamically.

for example:

```
string commandTypeFullName = "Namespace.MyFakeCommand"
Type cmdType = Type.GetType(commandTypeFullName);

var cmd1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strCommand, cmdType);
var cmd2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(cmdType);

GetExecutorFor(cmd1); // fails to find executor
GetExecutorFor(cmd2); // fails to find executor
```

So my question is how can i configure structure map to still find the exectors for dynamically instantiated objects?

Comment: This is definitely do-able (without resorting to dynamic keyword) - but I can't run the code right now to debug. What does the `cmd2` variable hold?

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce a non-generic `IExecutor` interface that all of your `IExecutor<T>` implement.

Then you use the `ObjectFactory.ForGenericType` method. See https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/v2.6.3/Source/StructureMap/ObjectFactory.cs#L310

```
var executor = ObjectFactory.ForGenericType(typeof(IExecutor<>)).
  WithParameters(cmdType).
  GetInstanceAs<IExecutor>()
```

Now `executor` will be an instance of the non-generic `IExecutor`, which should also have a Run method. The executor implements the non-generic `Run` method by casting the command object and passing it to the generic `Run` method.

Comment: Oh I see, your solution has solved my problem! It does require the extra non-generic run method, but I can definitely work with that. thank you

Comment: You should mark it as the Answer so that others know the question has been answered (without clicking through to read the comments).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about StructureMap (I use SimpleInjector) but this question isn't specific to the container, it's a question of generics.

You can usually achieve what you are trying to do using the dynamic keyword:

```
//slight tweak to your listed method so that it would work
public IExecutor<T> GetExecutorFor<T>(T instance)
{
    return IocContainer.GetAllInstances<IExecutor<T>>().FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

test code:

```
string commandTypeFullName = "Namespace.MyFakeCommand"
Type cmdType = Type.GetType(commandTypeFullName);

dynamic cmd1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strCommand, cmdType);
dynamic cmd2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(cmdType);

dynamic exec1 = GetExecutorFor(cmd1);
dynamic exec2 = GetExecutorFor(cmd2);
```

best practice should be to limit the use of dynamic - it gives no intellisense, has no compile time support etc. So I would go with this instead:

```
public void ExecuteCommand<T>(T command)
{
    IExecutor<T> executor = 
        IocContainer.GetAllInstances<IExecutor<T>>().FirstOrDefault(); 
    if (executor == null) throw new Exception();
    executor.Run(command)
}
```

test code:

```
string commandTypeFullName = "Namespace.MyFakeCommand"
Type cmdType = Type.GetType(commandTypeFullName);

dynamic cmd1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strCommand, cmdType);
dynamic cmd2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(cmdType);

ExecuteCommand(cmd1);
ExecuteCommand(cmd2);
```